# creating BitmapDrawable from path

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

i'm trying to create a Bitmap

```
 BitmapDrawable img = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), "res/drawable/wrench.png");
 Bitmap wrench = img.getBitmap();
 //Bitmap wrench = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wrench);
 canvas.drawColor(Color .BLACK);
 Log.d("OLOLOLO",Integer.toString(wrench.getHeight()));
 canvas.drawBitmap(wrench, left, top, null);
```

but when i call **wrench.getHeight()** program failed with NullPoinerException. (i put the file in drawable directory)
how can i solve my problem?

Comment: what happened when you did the BitmapFactory version?

Comment: bitmap factory version works fine, but i need to work with path(to construct it by some strings)

Comment: why do you need to construct it by strings? is it so that if you need a wrench you can add a wrench? 'cause there are better solutions for that that I'd be happy to show you - but you can't access the resources folder through a file path.

Comment: "wrench" is just for example. i have several files named like "human1Arm", "human2Head" etc. So i need create a bitmap for them. Numbers will be random. WARNING! when i create "human1Arm" bitmap from drawable, i need to create "human1WithoutArm" bitmap too. They are related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... I think I have a handle on your problem now.  Like I said, you can't access your drawables via a path, so if you want a human readable interface with your drawables that you can build programatically, declare a HashMap somewhere in your class:

```
private static HashMap<String, Integer> images = null;
```

Then initialize it in your constructor:

```
public myClass() {
  if (images == null) {
    images = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    images.put("Human1Arm", R.drawable.human_one_arm);
    // for all your images - don't worry, this is really fast and will only happen once
  }
}
```

Now for access -

```
String drawable = "wrench";
// fill in this value however you want, but in the end you want Human1Arm etc
// access is fast and easy:
Bitmap wrench = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), images.get(drawable));
canvas.drawColor(Color .BLACK);
Log.d("OLOLOLO",Integer.toString(wrench.getHeight()));
canvas.drawBitmap(wrench, left, top, null);
```

Comment: but path-version still haunts me((

Comment: @user1128677 I'm confused... do you still need help or did I cover it for you?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wrench);  
            Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
            matrix.postScale(0.2f, 0.2f);
            Bitmap dstbmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp,0,0,bmp.getWidth(),
            bmp.getHeight(),matrix,true);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);  
            canvas.drawBitmap(dstbmp, 10, 10, null);
```

"res/drawable/wrench.png" not valid path so either use images from sbcard if you are using images from drawable then use `R.drawable.wrench`

*It is not possible to get the exact path for an image , that is stored in drawable.*

**Why not?** When you compile your app to an *.apk file, all resources (ok, except from them in /raw) are compiled as well. You can only acces them, using their R. id.

**Solution?** Not really, you could copy them to a location on the sd card for example. No you know the location :)

Comment: in my code i have version that creates Bitmap from resourseId, but i need to wrk with String(path)

Comment: but on androiddevelopers http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html says, that path can be like "file location:
res/drawable/filename.png (.png, .jpg, or .gif)
The filename is used as the resource ID."

Comment: but we do't known where is `res/drawable/filename.png` on device

Comment: okay, so if device not have the SDcard? Mission Impossible?:D

Comment: not mission impossible use tempfile if imags size is not large

Comment: this is the one last way to create bitmaps from path?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
String imageNameWithoutExtension = "wrench";
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imageNameWithoutExtension, "drawable", getPackageName());
Bitmap dd = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
logo.setImageBitmap(dd);
```